# Why this wierd behaviours of Calendar class

Tags: java, calendar

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2019, 12, 29);
```

When i did `c.getTime()` i got the following output...

Output:

`Wed Jan 29 17:15:27 IST 2020`               // Should have been 2019

/////-------------------------------------------------------------//////

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2019, 11, 29);
```

When i did `c.getTime()` i got the following output...

Output:

`Sun Dec 29 17:18:23 IST 2019`

Now i don't know why **changing the Month from 12th to 11th gave me the correct date and time**, i would be really obliged if someone can explain this simply and if possible with a small uncomplicated example.

Comment: Yeah Months in `Calendar` starts from `zero` thats kinda weird. Better to use more efficient Library http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If you use JDK 8 you should prefer the java.time package to JODA.  It's been folded into the JDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Months in a `Calendar` are zero-based

> The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0

Assuming a Gregorian calendar, `11` is December, and `12` is January of next year, precisely the way your program shows it.

Answer (score 2):

Months start from 0, what you referenced with 12 is actually UNDECIMBER. So for Jan - Dec you use 0 - 11, 12 is a seperate month, so it rolled over the calendar to January of the next year.

See:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.UNDECIMBER

Answer (score 1):

```
public final void set(int year,
                      int month,
                      int date)
Sets the values for the calendar fields YEAR, MONTH, and DAY_OF_MONTH. Previous values of other calendar fields are retained. If this is not desired, call clear() first.
Parameters:
year - the value used to set the YEAR calendar field.
month - the value used to set the MONTH calendar field. Month value is 0-based. e.g., 0 for January.
date - the value used to set the DAY_OF_MONTH calendar field.
```

so  month  range 0-11 . when you use 12 it will go to next year.

ref:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int, int, int)